# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property [password] is not a valid property of class com.wolf.User in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to "run-app" my Grails app, but when it starts to add User and Admin via BootStrap it gives me this error

```
    Creating admin user
Fresh Database. Creating ADMIN user.
2017-12-05 19:20:48.191 ERROR --- [           main] o.g.events.gorm.GormAnnotatedListener    : Error triggering event [org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.PreInsertEvent[source=org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore@6491006]] for listener [public void com.wolf.UserPasswordEncoderListener.onPreInsertEvent(org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.PreInsertEvent)]: Property [password] is not a valid property of class com.wolf.User

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property [password] is not a valid property of class com.wolf.User
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.reflect.FieldEntityAccess$FieldEntityReflector.getPropertyWriter(FieldEntityAccess.java:279)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.reflect.FieldEntityAccess.setProperty(FieldEntityAccess.java:90)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.ModificationTrackingEntityAccess.setProperty(ModificationTrackingEntityAccess.groovy:41)
    at com.wolf.UserPasswordEncoderListener.encodePasswordForEvent(UserPasswordEncoderListener.groovy:31)
    at com.wolf.UserPasswordEncoderListener.onPreInsertEvent(UserPasswordEncoderListener.groovy:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
    at org.grails.events.gorm.GormAnnotatedListener$Trait$Helper.dispatch(GormAnnotatedListener.groovy:39)
    at com.wolf.UserPasswordEncoderListener.dispatch(UserPasswordEncoderListener.groovy)
    at org.grails.events.gorm.GormEventDispatcher.onPersistenceEvent(GormEventDispatcher.groovy:52)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.events.ConfigurableApplicationContextEventPublisher.publishEvent(ConfigurableApplicationContextEventPublisher.groovy:30)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.publishEvent(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:258)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onPreInsert(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:623)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onSaveOrUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:651)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:643)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:638)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi$_performSave_closure3.doCall(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:124)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.doInHibernate(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:299)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:243)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:117)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.performSave(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:242)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:159)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.wolf.User.save(User.groovy)
    at com.wolf.User.save(User.groovy)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at hubbub.BootStrap.createAdminUserIfRequired(BootStrap.groovy:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158)
    at hubbub.BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1087)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:535)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:528)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:504)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:74)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
    at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:261)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:387)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at hubbub.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

This started to happen when I installed Spring Security Core Plugin and changed my domain "User" property "password" with "passwordHash".
    Here is the User domain:

```
    package com.wolf

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

class User implements Serializable {

    String loginId
    String passwordHash
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired
    Date dateCreated

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']
    static hasOne = [ profile: Profile ]
    static hasMany = [ posts: Post, tags: Tag, following: User ]

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        (UserRole.findAllByUser(this) as List<UserRole>)*.role as Set<Role>
    }

    static constraints = {
        loginId size: 3..20, unique: true, blank: false
        tags()
        posts()
        profile nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        posts sort: "dateCreated", order: "desc"
    }

    String toString() { return "User $loginId (id: $id)" }
    String getDisplayString() { return loginId }
}
```

And last, here is the BootStrap code:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*
class BootStrap {    
def springSecurityService

    def init = { servletContext ->
        environments {
            development {
                if (!Post.count()) createSampleData()
            }
            test {
                if (!Post.count()) createSampleData()
            }
        }

//         Admin user is required for all environments
        createAdminUserIfRequired()
    }

    private createSampleData() {
        println "Creating sample data"

        def now = new Date()
        def chuck = new User(
                loginId: "chuck_norris",
                passwordHash: springSecurityService.encodePassword("highkick"),
                profile: new Profile(fullName: "Chuck Norris", email: "chuck@nowhere.net"),
                dateCreated: now).save(failOnError: true)
        def glen = new User(
                loginId: "glen",
                passwordHash: springSecurityService.encodePassword("sheldon"),
                profile: new Profile(fullName: "Glen Smith", email: "glen@nowhere.net"),
                dateCreated: now).save(failOnError: true)
        def peter = new User(
                loginId: "peter",
                passwordHash: springSecurityService.encodePassword("mandible"),
                profile: new Profile(fullName: "Peter Ledbrook", email: "peter@nowhere.net"),
                dateCreated: now).save(failOnError: true)
        def frankie = new User(
                loginId: "frankie",
                passwordHash: springSecurityService.encodePassword("testing"),
                profile: new Profile(fullName: "Frankie Goes to Hollywood", email: "frankie@nowhere.net"),
                dateCreated: now).save(failOnError: true)
        def sara = new User(
                loginId: "sara",
                passwordHash: springSecurityService.encodePassword("crikey"),
                profile: new Profile(fullName: "Sara Miles", email: "sara@nowhere.net"),
                dateCreated: now - 2).save(failOnError: true)
        def phil = new User(
                loginId: "phil",
                passwordHash: springSecurityService.encodePassword("thomas"),
                profile: new Profile(fullName: "Phil Potts", email: "phil@nowhere.net"),
                dateCreated: now)
        def dillon = new User(loginId: "dillon",
                passwordHash: springSecurityService.encodePassword("crikey"),
                profile: new Profile(fullName: "Dillon Jessop", email: "dillon@nowhere.net"),
                dateCreated: now - 2).save(failOnError: true)

        chuck.addToFollowing(phil)
        chuck.addToPosts(content: "Been working my roundhouse kicks.")
        chuck.addToPosts(content: "Working on a few new moves. Bit sluggish today.")
        chuck.addToPosts(content: "Tinkering with the hubbub app.")
        chuck.save(failOnError: true)

        phil.addToFollowing(frankie)
        phil.addToFollowing(sara)
        phil.save(failOnError: true)

        phil.addToPosts(content: "Very first post")
        phil.addToPosts(content: "Second post")
        phil.addToPosts(content: "Time for a BBQ!")
        phil.addToPosts(content: "Writing a very very long book")
        phil.addToPosts(content: "Tap dancing")
        phil.addToPosts(content: "Pilates is killing me")
        phil.save(failOnError: true)

        sara.addToPosts(content: "My first post")
        sara.addToPosts(content: "Second post")
        sara.addToPosts(content: "Time for a BBQ!")
        sara.addToPosts(content: "Writing a very very long book")
        sara.addToPosts(content: "Tap dancing")
        sara.addToPosts(content: "Pilates is killing me")
        sara.save(failOnError: true)

        dillon.addToPosts(content: "Pilates is killing me as well")
        dillon.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

        // We have to update the 'dateCreated' field after the initial save to
        // work around Grails' auto-timestamping feature. Note that this trick
        // won't work for the 'lastUpdated' field.
        def postsAsList = phil.posts as List
        postsAsList[0].addToTags(user: phil, name: "groovy")
        postsAsList[0].addToTags(user: phil, name: "grails")
        postsAsList[0].dateCreated = now.updated(year: 2004, month: MAY)

        postsAsList[1].addToTags(user: phil, name: "grails")
        postsAsList[1].addToTags(user: phil, name: "ramblings")
        postsAsList[1].addToTags(user: phil, name: "second")
        postsAsList[1].dateCreated = now.updated(year: 2007, month: FEBRUARY, date: 13)

        postsAsList[2].addToTags(user: phil, name: "groovy")
        postsAsList[2].addToTags(user: phil, name: "bbq")
        postsAsList[2].dateCreated = now.updated(year: 2009, month: OCTOBER)

        postsAsList[3].addToTags(user: phil, name: "groovy")
        postsAsList[3].dateCreated = now.updated(year: 2011, month: MAY, date: 1)

        postsAsList[4].dateCreated = now.updated(year: 2011, month: DECEMBER, date: 4)
        postsAsList[5].dateCreated = now.updated(year: 2012, date: 10)
        phil.save(failOnError: true)

        postsAsList = sara.posts as List
        postsAsList[0].dateCreated = now.updated(year: 2007, month: MAY)
        postsAsList[1].dateCreated = now.updated(year: 2008, month: APRIL, date: 13)
        postsAsList[2].dateCreated = now.updated(year: 2008, month: APRIL, date: 24)
        postsAsList[3].dateCreated = now.updated(year: 2011, month: NOVEMBER, date: 8)
        postsAsList[4].dateCreated = now.updated(year: 2011, month: DECEMBER, date: 4)
        postsAsList[5].dateCreated = now.updated(year: 2012, month: AUGUST, date: 1)

        sara.dateCreated = now - 2
        sara.save(failOnError: true)

        dillon.dateCreated = now - 2
        dillon.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
    }

    private createAdminUserIfRequired() {
        println "Creating admin user"
        if (!User.findByLoginId("admin")) {
            println "Fresh Database. Creating ADMIN user."

            def profile = new Profile(email: "admin@yourhost.com", fullName: "Administrator")
            def adminRole = new Role(authority: "ROLE_ADMIN").save(failOnError: true)
            def adminUser = new User(
                    loginId: "admin",
                    passwordHash: springSecurityService.encodePassword("secret"),
                    profile: profile,
                    enabled: true).save(failOnError: true)
            UserRole.create adminUser, adminRole, true
        }
        else {
            println "Existing admin user, skipping creation"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's related to Database Migration Plugin, but I checked every domain and no one has "password" as property.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... in "main/groovy/*package*/UserPasswordEncoderListener "encorePasswordForEvent" method had the old property "password" instead of "passwordHash".

Here's the method with old "password" property:

```
private void encodePasswordForEvent(AbstractPersistenceEvent event) {
    if (event.entityObject instanceof User) {
        User u = event.entityObject as User
        if (u.passwordHash && ((event instanceof  PreInsertEvent) || (event instanceof PreUpdateEvent && u.isDirty('password')))) {
            event.getEntityAccess().setProperty('password', encodePassword(u.passwordHash))
        }
    }
}
```

Here's with the new "passwordHash" property:

```
private void encodePasswordForEvent(AbstractPersistenceEvent event) {
    if (event.entityObject instanceof User) {
        User u = event.entityObject as User
        if (u.passwordHash && ((event instanceof  PreInsertEvent) || (event instanceof PreUpdateEvent && u.isDirty('passwordHash')))) {
            event.getEntityAccess().setProperty('passwordHash', encodePassword(u.passwordHash))
        }
    }
}
```